# Unable to create charts for all values in an entire column in Excel 2003

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2003, charts, report

My Excel data looks like this: (it's a lot bigger in fact)

```
code1 code2 01/08 02/08
X     A        12    10  
X     B         8    15
Y     A        52     0  
Y     B         5     5
```

Every day I add a column with extra data (the output of a SQL statement).

A chart with 4 series (X-A, X-B, Y-A and Y-B) and the dates on the X-axis, is easy.
I even found an [elaborate](http://www.tushar-mehta.com/excel/newsgroups/dynamic_charts/index.html#BasicRange) solution to make the chart grow as I add dates, but it's hard creating charts for "All Y's" or "All A's".

I could start creating subtotals separately, and charting those, but that's such a maintenance drag.

I've been told not to think of Excel as either a database, report generator or some kind of application deployment mechanism.

But can I get this happening in Excel 2003? Or do I have to look at another charting/reporting tool?

(I would not looking for a [Crystal Reports](http://www.sap.com/solutions/sapbusinessobjects/sme/reporting/crystalreports/index.epx) solution if that was the alternative, just something lightweight Office-like.)

Answer (score 5):

iReport will not function correctly without a connection to JasperServer. If you're looking for easy reports your best tools are really excel and access. As far as end-user simplicity the buck stops there.

If you're looking for something a bit more robust then I would take a look at any of the following for open source [solutions](http://sourceforge.net/search/?type_of_search=soft&words=reporting).

If you want to go commercial then you may want to leverage your SQL skills and use something like [Telerik reporting](http://www.telerik.com/products/reporting.aspx), [Monarch](http://www.datawatch.com/_products/monarch_pro.php), or DB Extra like Axxmasterr suggested. If you're looking for something a little more interactive and analytic you can try [Tableau](http://www.tableausoftware.com/), [Spotfire](http://spotfire.tibco.com/), or even [Xcelsius](http://www.sap.com/solutions/sapbusinessobjects/sme/reporting-dashboarding/index.epx).

Comment: +1 for mentioning Tableau. It's awesome software.

Comment: Another +1 for Tableau.

Answer (score 2):

What version of Excel are you using?

I know in Excel 2007 it's a snap to add a filter to a column and then create a chart from it. The chart changes automatically depending on what filters are set.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Excel 2003. 2007 sure looks better, but the functionality appears more or less the same. AutoFilter is a good tip, but convenient subtotals still seem lacking. Anyway, Excel still doesn't seem like the best reporting tool. Thanks! Jan

Answer (score 0):

I would check out [Open Source Reporting Tools](http://java-source.net/open-source/charting-and-reporting).  It is a bit pricey however I am sure you can find an eval copy out there to see if it really does what you need it to do.

[DB Extra](http://www.dbxtra.com/) is also another tool you can use if the open source tools do not work for you.

Comment: I'm not looking for libraries nor web based solutions. The only promising thing I found was iReport, but in v3.5.3 I downloaded, I got an exception when I want to create a report: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Called DataObject.find on null at org.openide.loaders.DataObject.find(DataObject.java:474). Duh.

Answer (score 0):

For what you are doing stick with Excel. And I say that as the CTO of a reporting product that would give you everything you want - but would be overkill for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You might find XLReport interesting. Excel based; it helps you to import your database easily into Excel as real time connected data sets. Check it out: www.xlreport.com.